# reads package javax.xml.soap from both java.xml.soap and java.xml.soap

Tags: java, module-info

My first project in Java for a few years.
I am on java 11 and my small project is a module compiled with maven.

I am getting this error:
`mymodule reads package javax.xml.soap from both java.xml.soap and java.xml.soap`

(The reason I have to use SOAP is historical)

The problem is that `java.xml.soap` is not showing up on my `mvn dependency:tree` so I have no idea what to exclude.

Any hints greatly appreciated

```html
module mymodule{
        requires javafx.controls;
        requires javafx.graphics;
        requires javafx.fxml;
        requires transitive lombok ;
        requires transitive org.postgresql.jdbc;
        requires java.xml;
        requires underscore;
        requires org.bouncycastle.provider;
        requires java.xml.soap;
        requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
        requires poi;
        requires poi.ooxml;
        requires spring.jdbc;
        requires jfxtras.controls;
        requires org.joda.time;
        requires spring.core;
        requires java.sql;
        requires org.apache.commons.text;
        requires com.google.gson;
        requires org.apache.commons.io;
        requires zip4j;
        }
```

and dependencies:

```html
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javadev</groupId>
            <artifactId>underscore</artifactId>
            <version>1.51</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-RC3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/javax.xml.soap-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2-b01</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/.-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hierynomus/smbj -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hierynomus</groupId>
            <artifactId>smbj</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfxtras/jfxtras-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfxtras-controls</artifactId>
            <version>10.0-r1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: I think there's a conflict between `requires java.xml.soap;` and `requires java.xml;`. Is the problem fixed if you remove `requires java.xml.soap;`? You should still be able to use java.xml.soap since its inside the java.xml package.

Comment: Thanks a million. In intellij, the red line disappears from the top of the module-info.java
But now I get this compilation error: java: package javax.xml.soap is not visible

Comment: You're welcome. I think you need to remove this line `requires java.xml.soap;`. Please DO NOT remove `requires java.xml;`. Probably this should resolve the issue.

Comment: That did not sollve it :(